# How to use condition in LINQ take() method

Tags: linq

How to join two tables and get the records based on the class B variable values

```
Class A
{
    RecordID int {get;set;}

    Name string {get;set;}
}

Class B
{
    Name string {get;set;}

    DataToPick int  {get;set;}
}
```

My inputs are

```
Class A
---------------------
RecordID name

1        Sathish

2        Sathish

3        Kumar

4        Kumar

5        Ajay

Class B
--------------------------------------
Name   DataToPick

Sathish   1

kumar     2
```

Now i want to join two tables and get the values from Class A i.e 3 records, based on the Class B variable (Datatopick)

Please help to write it in LINQ like below

```
var qry= (from c in classA
          join d in ClassB on c.name equals d.name
         select c).take(d.datatopick)
```

Comment: `d.datatopick` is not a single record, here I can see `1,2`, which one will you consider

Answer (score 1):

You can group `ClassA` and then select the `DataToPick` from the other list.

```
var result = 
     classA.GroupBy(a => a.Name)
           .SelectMany(g => g.Take(classB.Where(b => b.Name == g.Key)
                                         .Select(b => b.DataToPick)
                                         .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                                         .Single()));
```

Even better join first and the take:

```
var result = classA.Join(classB, a => a.Name, b => b.Name, (a, b) => new {a, b.DataToPick})
                   .GroupBy(arg => new {arg.a.Name, arg.DataToPick})
                   .SelectMany(g => g.Select(arg => arg.a).Take(g.Key.DataToPick));
```

Comment: Datatopick is the no of records to be picked from Class A which are all matched from classA.name =ClassB.name

Comment: Sorry, I totally mis-understood you before. I've edited to reflect your real issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could `join` classA and classB, group by `Name, DataToPick` and use `Take` like that

```
(from a in listA
join b in listB on a.Name equals b.Name
group new { a, b } by new { a.Name, b.DataToPick } into gr
select new
{
    Name = gr.Key.Name,
    ListA = gr.Select(x=>x.a).Take(gr.Key.DataToPick)
}
).SelectMany(x => x.ListA).ToList();
```